# Dependency between JUnit tests that work on multiple devices simultaneously

Tags: android, junit

I created a network application in Android.
In order to test it I need multiple devices that work simultaneously, and transmit data between them.
Currently I use ADB to run automated instrumented tests on multiple devices, where each device run a different test.
The problem with this approach is that I can only run a single JUnitTest on each device, and once the test is over, I need to initialize another test using ADB.
I would prefer to use some kind of agent which runs on each device and waits for testing scenarios to be run.
Is there something like this that I can use? Maybe a testing framework I'm not familiar with?

[image]